# What code is already run when I open PySpark in a shell?

Tags: shell, apache-spark, terminal, pyspark, jupyter-notebook

If I want to run PySpark in Jupyter Notebook, I would

1) run the command "Jupyter Notebook" in my Linux terminal to open a notebook in my Google Chrome browser

2) type the following code to initialize PySpark

```
from pyspark import SparkContext
sc = SparkContext("local", "First App")
```

3) run `sc.stop()` to exit Spark Context

However, if I run PySpark within my terminal, I simply need to run the command `pyspark`, and I can skip step #2 above.

My questions:

A) Why is step #2 not needed when running PySpark within my Linux terminal?

B) What other code is already run or initialized if I run PySpark within my Linux terminal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, PySpark shell has SparkContext available as ‘sc’, so no need to create SparkContext again. Also SparkSession is available as spark if your spark version is 2.0 or above.